# Keep the Focus on a custom (User)Control in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls, mouse

Say, I need to move a custom (User)Control in a form, using the keyboard.

The behavior is simple: the user clicks the control, then it can move it using the keyboard (up/d/l/r).

In this sample instead of a UserControl, I will use a Canvas.

The problem is that when I "focalize" my control, or I loose it after a coup of 'steps' for the textBox, or I don't recieve it at all...

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication14.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        PreviewKeyDown="Window_PreviewKeyDown">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Name="textBox1" 
                 Margin="91,66,292,223" Width="120" 
                 Text="Good morning, miss Hilton!"/>
        <Canvas Name="canvas1" Focusable="True"
                Margin="124,112,179,99" Width="200"
                Background="AliceBlue"
                MouseDown="canvas1_MouseDown"
                PreviewKeyDown="canvas1_PreviewKeyDown"  />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

CS:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void canvas1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("canvas_MouseDown 0, canvas1.IsFocused? {0}",
            canvas1.IsFocused);

        canvas1.Focus();

        Console.WriteLine("canvas_MouseDown 1, canvas1.IsFocused? {0}",
            canvas1.IsFocused);
    }

    private void canvas1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("canvas_PreviewKeyDown, canvas1.IsFocused? {0}",
            canvas1.IsFocused);

        if (canvas1.IsFocused)
            MoveCanvas(e.Key);
    }

    private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("Window_PreviewKeyDown, canvas1.IsFocused? {0}",
        //    canvas1.IsFocused);

        //if (canvas1.IsFocused)
        //    MoveCanvas(e.Key);
    }

    void MoveCanvas(Key key)
    {
        int delta = 10;
        switch (key)
        {
            case Key.Left: canvas1.Margin = new Thickness(
                canvas1.Margin.Left - delta,
                canvas1.Margin.Top,
                canvas1.Margin.Right,
                canvas1.Margin.Bottom);
                break;
            case Key.Up: canvas1.Margin = new Thickness(
                canvas1.Margin.Left,
                canvas1.Margin.Top - delta,
                canvas1.Margin.Right,
                canvas1.Margin.Bottom + delta);
                break;
            case Key.Right: canvas1.Margin = new Thickness(
                canvas1.Margin.Left,
                canvas1.Margin.Top,
                canvas1.Margin.Right - delta,
                canvas1.Margin.Bottom);
                break;
            case Key.Down: canvas1.Margin = new Thickness(
                canvas1.Margin.Left,
                canvas1.Margin.Top + delta,
                canvas1.Margin.Right,
                canvas1.Margin.Bottom - delta);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Bellow is the execution log after mouse down on the control and three "keyUp"s:

```
   canvas_MouseDown 0, canvas1.IsFocused? False ' before click '
   canvas_MouseDown 1, canvas1.IsFocused? True  ' after click ' 
Window_PreviewKeyDown, canvas1.IsFocused? True  ' up 1 '
canvas_PreviewKeyDown, canvas1.IsFocused? True  ' up 1 '
Window_PreviewKeyDown, canvas1.IsFocused? False ' up 2 '
Window_PreviewKeyDown, canvas1.IsFocused? False ' up 3 '
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things you can try:

1. Set e.Handled to true if you are handing the event. This should prevent other things from reacting to the key stroke as well.
2. You may need to play around with the [KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigation.directionalnavigation.aspx) setting on all the ancestor controls. The arrow keys by default will move the keyboard focus, but that's based on the DirectionalNavigation setting. You'd want to set it to None, but this is assuming #1 doesn't correct the issue.

Comment: setting Handled to true helped very well. Thanks!